# Enable/Disable Laptop Display w/ Hotkey

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, hotkeys

Is there a program that can disable (turn off) a laptop's display with a hotkey and require the same hotkey to be pressed to re-enable it?

I would just close the lid but I prefer having that set to make it hibernate, don't wish to keep changing my power profiles just to turn off the display manually. Would also be a good child deterrent as they'd see it won't come on after moving the mouse.

I'm aware I could just lock the system and set the screen to turn off after being idle for a few minutes... but I'd rather not have to lock it and the turn off after idle for a few minutes can be annoying when watching a TV show or longer YouTube video...

Comment: Would you want the program to also capture key presses as well as mouse clicks and discard them until the hot key to enable is pressed? Would an application that displays a full screen, black rectangle, staying in the foreground, and waiting for a particular key press while discarding any other input work for you?

Comment: I'm not concerned about ignoring keypresses and stuff, if there's a program that does that too, great - but not something I'm actively seeking. Just something that powers off the monitor. Not really looking for a program that just makes the screen black, I know there are plenty of those categorized as pranks or privacy applications.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a program that can disable (turn off) a laptop's display?

[nircmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/) from [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) can be used to enable/disable the monitor.

You can put these commands in a batch file and attach hotkeys as appropriate for your needs.

> ```
> monitor [action]
> ```
>
> Changes the state of the display monitor. The [action] parameter may
>   contain the following values:
>
> ```
> off: Turn off the monitor
> on: Turn on the monitor
> ```

Source [NirCmd Command Reference - monitor](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/monitor.html)

Examples:

```
nircmd monitor off
nircmd monitor on
```

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: I saw that, unfortunately it merely puts it in standby meaning any keypress or movement of the mouse will wake it up. It almost does what I want, but I want to require a specific hotkey to turn the displays back on.